# ZVS Driver - Why does so much current need to flow through the diodes?

Tags: oscillator, flyback, zvs

Here is a diagram for a simple ZVS driver:

[image: ZVS driver simple]

So as the voltage one side of the LC circuit goes up, it pulls down the gate of the MOSFET on the opposite side, through the diode (D3 and D4). The current going into the diodes is limited by the 470 ohm resistors, if I'm correct.

However, I don't see why the resistor values are so low. Having such a low value means needing a diode and resistor with higher wattage ratings, and more heating, etc.

Since the pull down resistors are 10kohm, R3 and R4 just have to be lower resistance than the pull down resistors (R1 and R2), say 1kohm, or something like that...are there any problems that would arise from doing that?

EDIT: Ignore the input voltage on the diagram - I will know the voltage beforehand

Also, unrelated, but how do I know the best value for the caps?

Comment: A critical control parameter is the external series gate resistor. This dampens down peak drain-source voltage and very importantly prevents gate ringing caused by lead inductance and parasitic capacitance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gate of a MOSFET is effectively one plate of a capacitor, with the other plate(s) being the internal semiconductor materials. In order to turn on the MOSFET this capacitor must first be "charged up". The speed of its charging is based on the current applied according to the formula, $$I=C\frac{dV}{dt}$$
If resistance was added on the MOSFET gates, the "capacitors" would charge up more slowly due to the decreased current, which would delay the switching of the capacitors. This is often undesirable, because if the transistors take too long to switch on then the switching would no longer be ZVS, as they would actually turn on a bit too late, potentially causing damage. I expect the resistor was selected as the maximum possible value for this particular design while still allowing the transistors to switch fast enough for the circuit to work properly.

Comment: Ah I see...Thanks for the quick answer. Also, could you give an idea of how fast the mosfets charge? Or their capacitance?

Comment: MOSFET gate capacitance should be on the datasheet.

Comment: In the datasheet for your MOSFETs look for the "Gate to Emitter Charge" value. When you find it, you can determine how fast it'll switch with different amounts of current using the formula: $$I=\frac{Q}{t}$$ where *I* is the current, *Q* is the gate charge, and *t* is the time it will take to "charge" up. This will give you a rough idea, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

40V on the gate would be too much - it's limited by the 12V zeners. A voltage divider is not an alternative due the large range of the supply voltage. 470 Ohm is selected to have a fast enough charging for fet gate also when the supply voltage is low.

The turnoff at the state flipping is accelerated by discharging the gate of the opposite fet through D3, D4. Unfortunately that also sinks some current via R3,R4. It's as much as 85 mA when the supply voltage is 40V.

The capacitor: It makes the resonance with the inductance of the transformer. The frequency is determined in this way. This circuit could operate without the capacitor, but the frequency would be little difficult to predict. Two other mechanism would maybe fight to determine the frequency:

- the inductor core finally magnetically saturates when dc current builds up, the saturation makes the induction to collapse and the state flips.
- stray capacitances take the place of the drawn capacitor

The transformer+C1 should be a LC resonator that has a resonant frequency

- high enough to be unhearable and to prevent the magnetic saturation state to be achieved.
- low enough to give to the stray capacitances and inductances too much influence

C1 is not a single capacitor, but a network

- to keep the inductance low and
- to have the wanted voltage rating with low cost parts

Addendum: if the input is constant 40VDC, then select

- R3 = R4 = 1200 Ohm
- R1 = R2 = 470 Ohm

D1 and D2 can be removed, the new voltage dividers make 12 volts to the gates. Exactly only 11.25 V but that should be enough because 10 volts was enough.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! So if I knew the input voltage will always be 40v, could I use high valued resistors? Also what do you mean by a voltage divider (where in the circuit would it go)?

Comment: @AJC added new data